# VBA loop to copy & paste range of specific columns to another workbook multiple times

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to figure out the quickest **Loop** method to copy a range of columns ("A16:J1338") from a source workbook, to a specific column (C1) of a specific workbook, 10 times. I would like to that macro to paste the data below the last available blank cell (under COL C)

Here's my code;

```
Sub copy_Loop()
Dim LastRow As Long
Range("A16:J1338").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Manzurfa\Desktop\1. Forecast Amalgamation.xlsx"
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Merrell CA Forecast Template - Alain Travers.xlsm").Activate
Range("K18:O1338").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("1. Forecast Amalgamation.xlsx").Activate
Range("K3").Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("Merrell CA Forecast Template - Alain Travers.xlsm").Activate
Range("A16:J1338").Select
Selection.Copy
 Windows("1. Forecast Amalgamation.xlsx").Activate     
Range("B1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActivCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
ActivCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

The columns ("A16:J1338") have blank rows in between and I would like the macro to overlook the blanks and loop the copy-paste under the last available blank cell.

I would be very grateful for any help on this.

Comment: Just look at all those `.Select` lines... that it going to run REALLY slow.

Answer (score 0):

You have FAR too many `.Select` commands, you can tell excel where to write data without them. In addition you need to set the workbooks and worksheets as variables, given that there names are incredibly long, tidying up things.

Then you can get rid of the selections with a basic 
`wsTo.Range("B1").Resize(1, Range.Columns.Count).value = wsFr.Range("A16:J1338").value`
This is just conceptual, you would need to create your range, worksheet, and workbook variables. Also turning off calculations and screen updating will go a long way.

I would reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCSF5tq7pZ0 as an all in one package for speeding up your macros, big or small.